# He helped the Indians win

Tags: grammar, infinitives

> *Christopher Columbus discovered America and was the Indians' best friend. He helped the Indians win their war against Frederick Douglass and freed the Hebrews from Napoleon…*

This is a part from the famous surrealistic speech by Mr. Garrison from the TV series *South Park* (quoted according the comic version). I would like to ask why "to" is omitted before the verb "win". Does it have dealings with the differences between American English and British English?

Answer (score 6):

> …why "to" is omitted before the verb "win".

The verb "help" *can* come with a bare infinitive.

> Building a better army will help protect our land from the outcasts.
>
> Help me clean the hall and I will buy you that delicious ice cream.
>
> Sending *Curiosity* to Mars will help nourish the curious nature of astronomers.